# Is there a way to check my achievements inside the game?

Tags: diablo-iii, achievements

I saw that is possible to check my achievements in my profile screen (where I can start the game or chose the quest) by right clicking in my hero and choosing achievement.

How can I (if possible) check in-game my achievements?

Comment: Why down-vote my question? Please leave comments. This is a perfect question there is no problem in my POV

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are three ways to check your achievements in-game:

1) (*Easiest*) **Press <kbd>Y</kbd> in-game at any time** to bring up the achievements window.

2) **Press <kbd>Esc</kbd> or the in-game button to bring up the settings menu, and select "achievements" from there.**

3) As of [Patch 1.05](http://diablo.gamepedia.com/Diablo_III_Patches#Patch_1.0.5), there is a **button for achievements in-game**.

Comment: Thanks =) I was testing yesterday, but couldn't find that (after some beer everything is hard to see).

Comment: no worries mate, was having trouble with viewing the starcraft achievements a while back :P